# How to setup a git lfs server at home?

Tags: git, github, git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

I am making use of `git lfs` for storage of large files in a github repository. The only problem is that there is a quota for `git lfs`; specifically you can only store 1 GB and only stream (download) 1 GB per month. After you run out of that, you must pay $5 for 5 more GB. This could become expensive.

I have an old PC I could boot Linux and port forward on.

Does anyone know how to setup a `git lfs` server at home rather than using Github's lfs built in CPU's?

Comment: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Implementations

Comment: Giftless one has a good docs and quickstart guide: https://giftless.datopian.com/en/latest/quickstart.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a [variety of implementations](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Implementations) that you can use, and there's a [reference server implementation](https://github.com/git-lfs/lfs-test-server) you can use for testing or production use.

Comment: But this does not explain how do you configure git to use your server for lfs and continue to use GitHub for the rest.

Comment: Is there any information about git lfs reference client implementation too somewhere? I'm looking for alternative client applications that don't use Go.

Comment: I'm not aware of alternate client implementations that aren't bridges.  If they existed, they would be listed on the same wiki page.

Answer (score 5):

Starting with git-lfs version [2.10.0](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/pull/3918) (released 2020-01-21) it's now possible to `git lfs push` and `fetch` against bare repos on the local file system (i.e. with the remote URL set to `file://...` or even with `/path/to/bare-repo.git`).

For example:

```bash
git clone /path/to/local-git-repo.git
cd local-git-repo
echo 'hello world' > hello.txt
git lfs track '/hello.txt'
git add .
```

This will create a local `.git/lfs/objects` directory.

```
git commit -m 'Add, track LFS file'
git push
```

This will push lfs objects to `/path/to/local-git-repo.git/lfs/objects`.

You'll probably need to setup git lfs in your global config if it isn't there already.

```bash
git config --global filter.lfs.clean 'git-lfs clean -- %f'
git config --global filter.lfs.process 'git-lfs filter-process'
git config --global filter.lfs.required 'true'
git config --global filter.lfs.smudge 'git-lfs smudge -- %f'
```

Comment: is it possible to push to github as a remote while pushing only LFS objects to a local server (via file:// protocol)?

Comment: @Chad I'm not sure why you would want to do that; anyone who clones the repo from Github will not be able to clone the repo as they won't receive the LFS files.

Comment: @Chad I suppose if you really wanted to keep huge files out of your code repo, you could try using a separate repo for your big files, then symlink them into your main repo. Git tracks symlinks just fine.