# Azure Function app + private bitbucket + git lfs

Tags: azure-functions

I'm looking to deploy to Azure Function app (written in `python` and running on `Linux`) from a private Bitbucket Git repository. Initially, the deployment process was smooth. However, after adding one file (`deps/llm_evaluator-1.1.2-py3-none-any.whl`) to Git LFS (Large File Storage), I encountered an issue with deploying from Git.

The error message in the Azure portal's Deployment Center reads as follows:

`git-lfs smudge 'deps/llm_evaluator-1.1.2-py3-none-any.whl': 1: git-lfs: not found\nerror: external filter 'git-lfs smudge %f' failed 127\nerror: external filter 'git-lfs smudge %f' failed\nfatal: deps/llm_evaluator-1.1.2-py3-none-any.whl: smudge filter LFS failed\n\n/usr/bin/git checkout dev --force`

I've found some suggestions in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/faq), but they seem to be applicable only to GitHub and GitHub Actions.

Is there a method to enable Git LFS for a Git repository that isn't hosted on GitHub?

I tried to find information of azure function documentation, but found nothing.

Comment: Could please tell what type of code you are using c#, python, etc in the Azure function, if possible share the sample code  used

Comment: I'm using python. In lfs I have just one file `deps/llm_evaluator-1.1.2-py3-none-any.whl` but this file isn't actually used in FA. The file is used for testing on local. The error appears before building the application (git lfs is probably missing on FA, but I couldn't find, how to install it or enable it)

Comment: Hope this reference [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66307854/how-to-setup-a-git-lfs-server-at-home#:~:text=You%27ll%20probably%20need%20to%20setup%20git%20lfs%20in,git%20config%20--global%20filter.lfs.smudge%20%27git-lfs%20smudge%20--%20%25f%27)

Comment: Refer to this SO [for](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cicd-implementation-for-an-azure-function-app-using-atlassian-bamboo-server/) development [guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66161947/python-azure-functions-and-bitbucket-pipelines-how-do-i-zip-requirements)

Answer (score 0):

Steps to enable Git LFS on a private Bitbucket repository to an Azure Function app.

- `git clone /path/to/local-git-repo.git`, will clone your remote repository to your local machine. The second command, `cd local-git-repo`, will change your directory to the newly cloned repository.
- `echo 'hello world' > hello.txt`, creates a new file called `hello.txt` with the text "hello world" in it. The following command, `git lfs track '/hello.txt'`, tracks the file `hello.txt` with Git LFS.
- `git add .` and `git commit -m 'Add, track LFS file'`, add and commit the changes to your repository. Finally, the command `git push` pushes the changes to your remote repository.

[image]
**In order to enable git lfs refer below:-**

- `git config --global filter.lfs.clean 'git-lfs clean -- %f'`
- `git config --global filter.lfs.process 'git-lfs filter-process'`
- `git config --global filter.lfs.required 'true'` `git config --global filter.lfs.smudge 'git-lfs smudge -- %f'`

configure your global Git configuration to use Git LFS.

I have tried the above steps in a sample Azure function like the below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- I refer to this SO [for](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cicd-implementation-for-an-azure-function-app-using-atlassian-bamboo-server/) development [guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66161947/python-azure-functions-and-bitbucket-pipelines-how-do-i-zip-requirements).